# minikube start - multiple times

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

When I do a `minikube start` I get:

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
Kubectl is now configured to use the cluster.
Loading cached images from config file.
```

However, if I do this again I get the same output.

Is this creating a new cluster, reprovisioning the existing cluster or just doing nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minikube start` resumes the old cluster that is paused/stoped.

But if you delete the `minikube machine` by `minikube delete` or manually delete from virtualbox, `minikube start` will create a new cluster in that case.

Answer (score 0):

> **MINIKUBE** is a lightweight kubernetes implementation that creates a VM on your
>   local machine.
>   and deploys a cluster containing only **one** **NODE**.
>   so basically **MINIKUBE** is the only **NODE** in the Kubernetes cluster.

Any multiple attempts to start the minikube  is directed to create ONE NODE ONLY.

```
$ kubectl get nodes
```

this return minikube node

but i came across this link which provides info on creating multiple nodes [multi node cluster](https://medium.com/devopslinks/deploying-multi-node-kubernetes-environment-in-your-local-machine-a66a1eb82e36)